# Maven map a file

Tags: file, maven, mapping

In Maven, is there a way to map one file to another file with a different name?  I know there is a way to map a file to a different file with the same name under a certain directory  with the following:

```
<mapping>
  <directory>/some/path/to/dir</directory>
  <sources>
    <source>/some/path/to/file/xyz</source>
  </sources>
</mapping>
```

This will map `/some/path/to/file/xyz` to `/some/path/to/dir/xyz`.  Instead I'd like to have `/some/path/to/file/xyz` be mapped to `/some/path/to/dir/abc`.  Is there a clean maven way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No directly. You can use Ant's [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) via the [antrun maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). See [Mapping File Names](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase> <!-- a lifecycle phase --> </phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <copy todir="/some/path/to/dir">
              <fileset dir="/some/path/to/file/"/>
              <mapper/><!-- you'll make the name mapping configuration here-->
            </copy>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I ended up using the antrun plugin to copy and rename the file by doing copy->move task.  Thanks for answer.